# Javascript - Read JSON by dynamic url inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have to make a call to a json that varies according to the id that I pass in the url, for this I must go through an array of identifiers and modify the url of the json inside the loop. **But unfortunately it doesn't go inside the json function until the loop iterations have finished**.

```
var IdList = ['1401', '5724', '5802', '3502', '2101'];

for(l = 0; l < IdList.length; l++){
   $.getJSON('https://www.urljson.com?id='+IdList[l]+'', function(emp) {
      price = emp.data.price;
      currency = emp.data.currency;
   });
}
```

Could someone tell me what is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: `$.getJSON` is async. It returns immediately but its actions happen later.

Comment: @Ouroboros So what is happening is that the json call is executed before the `IdList[l]` variable gives it a value?

Comment: No. `function(emp)` happens well after the loop (and code after the loop) has completed.

Comment: As written, the function appears to make a call to the JSON for each Id in the list just fine, the callback just has to wait for the network request. i.e. the only "modification" to the url inside the loop is already happening successfully. What is the actual code presenting the issue?